# How to manually create a SQLAlchemy query object?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

My goal is to mock my DAO class's methods so that I can preform unit tests without having to send a request to the database.

Currently, my plan is to use mock to set the return type of a specific method that returns a object of type `sqlalchemy.engine.row.Row`. However, I cannot find documentation on how to manually create this object.

Can someone point me in the right direction or show me how to create that object?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52357483/14316282) help?

Comment: No, it does not for my specific use case. My code is vastly different than their setup and I cannot simply mock the connection object

Comment: I am looking for the answer on how to create a sqlalchemy.engine.row.Row object so that I can manually set a return value of an method

Comment: You could possibly substitute a named tuple - `Row` tries to emulate its API.

Comment: I'll give that a try

Answer (score 0):

Just for futur vistors who might land on this page, as pointed out by [snakecharmerb-on-strike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5320906/snakecharmerb-on-strike?tab=profile), using a python builtin [named tuple](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) will do the job.